Framedrops in threeJS
So I have a pretty weird case where a threeJS application seems to run fine on one machine (with all thinkable browsers) but not at all on other machines (chrome).
I have gotten a profile trace from one of the "broken" machines, and I can see that chrome is dropping roughly 9 out of 10 frames, causing it to of course lag quite a bit.
My animate loop seems to run quite fast and generally finishes within 4ms.
However from time to time I get a LongAnimationFrame of roughly 1 second, but without any reasonable work.
from chrome://tracing

It doesn't look like it is doing that much work, but still blocking the main thread.
Incidentally it is the same on firefox.

it does the work that I expect it to do, and then it just stops the world for almost a full second.
I've also checked memory usage, and it stays between 12 and 15mb, so nothing to write home about.
So to get a distinct question out of this, what can cause this behavior of the browser just sitting around waiting?
And is there any more reasonable troubleshooting I can do?
edit:
Not really new info, but I added some stats (that I report myself) and I can see that it takes 100-200ms between 2 calls to my animate method (that does all computation and requests to webgl render), but the time for the animate method to complete is 2-5ms, so there is something blocking me from refreshing more often
